# How do I return a value that is not in it's own row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of serial numbers that have different scan dates:

`Serial #    Started         Ended           Count
L50099      28-02-14 11:50  28-02-14 15:20  1
L50099      25-11-15 15:55  25-11-15 19:25  2
L50098      03-03-16 11:30  03-03-16 15:00  1
L50099      01-07-16 13:37  01-07-16 17:07  3`

How do I return the cell of the previously Ended date?

For example, how do I return **03/03/16 3:00 PM** *(row C, Ended column)* into row D in the Prev column? And the rest for all the others?

My actual data will have a heap of other serial numbers and dates in between, this is just an example.

I'm trying index/match and vlookup but it's fixated onto the same column, not one previous to it.

EDIT: Can I use INDEX MATCH MATCH to get the date for the serial # of the count, minus 1, which is the date of the previous count?

*The formula for the Count column is =COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)*

Answer (score 1):

In D2 put this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:C1,MATCH(2,IF($A$1:A1=A2,1))),"No Previous")
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're starting at row 1, the column titles?

Comment: Because it needs to be confirmed as an array, does that mean it can't also be used within another formula?

Comment: @BBking I start at row one because we need to look at all the rows above the current one.  The second part of the range is not absolute and there for will increase as the formula is filled down from A1 to A2 to A3 ...  As to if it can be used in another formula depends on the other formula.

Comment: I've got a count column. Maybe that can help?